# Send Firebase registration token after PHP login in webView

Tags: php, android, firebase, android-webview, firebase-notifications

i really hope someone can help me out.

I have Firebase set up in my android app that is displaying a webView of my website i have built using CakePHP 3. Firebase notifications do work when i manually add the device token to the database but what i'm finding hard to understand is how would i get the registration token after login, so i can merge it with the user_id and save them to the database.

**UPDATE**

The code i have now is able to send the token to my PHP server. If i store the token straight to the database it works fine but i need to merge the token with the user_id when they login, so i need to store the token in a session (see PHP code below for example) but when i try using `$session->read('device_id')` it is empty.

I'm thinking it may have something to do with my MainActivity webView deleting the current PHP session when it loads the onCreate() method but im not to sure.

Here is the code for setting the session token in PHP.

StoreTokenToSession (PHP)

```
public function index()
{
    $session = $this->request->session();

    if(isset($_GET['device_id']))
    {
        // Store in session until login
        $session->write('device_id', $_GET['device_id']);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("notifications");
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

    }
    else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true);
    }
    else
    {
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    }

    webView.loadUrl("example.com");
}
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("example.com?device_id="+token)
            .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to have various tries in here. I'd abandon the efforts with a webview, it looks like more pain than it's worth. But the one in `sendRegistrationToServer()` is commented out. If you enable that code (and remove the webview stuff), what happens?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I know that firebase getToken() is called asynchronously and so i have to wait for the token to load. The question now is, how would i load the app, then wait for the token to come through and once the token is there send it to PHP, then finally show the user the login section. I was thinking of a splashscreen but wouldn't know how to implement it as i'm new to android

Comment: `onTokenRefresh()` will be invoked when the token is refreshed, so you don't have to wait for it. You *might* have to wait for the `OkHttpClient` request though, since that will be an async call too. But I haven't used OkHttp and in general I don't think there's a lot of need to wait in this simple code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sometimes when i first load my app, the token is  null, that must have something to with the token not been available. how could i implement something like `splashscreen -> if(noToken){ continue with splashscreen until token and then remove splashscreen for main activity } ` any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Uhm.. that's application flow, something I'm not really fluent in. Sorry!

Comment: No problem. I have updated my question, could you have a look please and if there's any advice u could give me, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is this now the remaining problem? " i need to merge the token with the user_id when they login, so i need to store the token in a session"

Comment: Yes that's the only remaining problem. When i store the token in the session `$session->write('device_id', $_GET['device_id']);` and come to read the session `$session->read('device_id')` during the login proccess, it is empty

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late to help you with that, and also probably not the best way to do it either, but our solution to this was to pass the token along the URL as base64 when calling the webview and then storing it on the session... once the login was made, we saved the token in the session to the logged user.

Something like this:

```
String kDeviceToken = "https://hostname.com?deviceToken=%s";
String token = SessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getFirebaseToken();
byte[] data = token.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
String url = String.format(kDeviceToken, base64);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Providing further detail of your answer, could help any users that find their way here from Google. One of my answers that was not accepted still gets me rep occasionally from the odd upvote.

Comment: @MatheusDardenne what's SessionManager? And do I need to import the files of Firebase into my mainactivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the username in a place where the service can find it. Say you're using an auth state listener (this code would typically be somewhere in the activity where you register the user):

```
FirebaseAuth
    .getInstance()
    .addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        public void onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            setCurrentUser(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .edit()
            .putString("uid", mUsername)
            .commit();
        }
    });
```

This stores the uid in the shared preferences, which are available anywhere in your app. So that means that in your service, you can retrieve the uid:

```
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    String uid = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("uid", null);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("example.com?device_id="+token+"&uid="+uid)
        .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So we read the uid, get the token and send them both off to the server.

There is a potential race condition in here: if the first token comes in before the user is signed in, `sendRegistrationToServer` won't have a uid yet. I'll leave that part as an exercise for the reader as it's really just invoking the same code for that second flow.

Comment: That code would be perfect but login and registration are all done via CakePHP through the webView, so I can't get the username. Am I missing something simple here or is it complicated? I have been working on this for the last 4 days straight so I can't tell lol

Answer (score -1):

I know it may be so late but i was searching for this problem and i finnaly figure out a solution which may be useful.

you can send your token as post in the url you request, and then in your php you catch this post parameter and put it in session so when you loggin successfully you can send this session value to data base with user id and this also will give you the ability to make token connected with active account which mean if user log out and log in with new account the token will be connected to new user id but you have to make sure that the sent token not connected with other user and if it connected you have to change this user id to the new one